# Shutdown computer when download/upload ends

Tags: networking, download, power-management, shutdown, upload

I often want to turn the computer off for the night (yes I'm one of those) but am in in the middle of uploading or downloading something. Is there a utility that shuts a windows computer down when the network is idle for a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 1):

If you are just downloading stuff off sites, then [Getright](http://www.getright.com/) and [FlasghGet](http://www.filehippo.com/download_flashget/) both have options to shutdown the computer when downloading completes.

If you are downloading using torrents, then [uTorrent](http://www.utorrent.com/) has an option to shutdown or restart upon completion as well.

Flashget and uTorrent are both freeware. Getright used to be shareware but now it might be a demo+paid model

Answer (score 0):

Many download "helper" programs have an option to shut down the computer after a download is finished. I know CuteFTP did at one point.

This means you would have to download all files through this program, though.

I don't remember any of the other programs as I stopped using them after I didn't have dial-up anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Not that I know of, but you can probably write a script to reference the WMI information regarding your network usage.  Another metric might be to poll the last modified times of the folders which you are downloading to.